# ld skipping incompatible library when g++ compiling with either -m32 or -m64

Tags: linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries, ld

I'm on 64-bit Ubuntu and I'm trying to build with "libasmlibrary.so" with Eclipse. However, it kept telling me that the library is incompatible, either with "-m32" or "-m64". This is what is shown when I don't add either of the two options.

> 17:25:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project ASM_TEST ****
>
> make all
>
> Building target: ASM_TEST
>
> Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
>
> g++ -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/leon/asmlibrary/linux -o "ASM_TEST"  ./src/demo_fit.o ./src/video_camera.o ./src/vjfacedetect.o   -lopencv_core -lasmlibrary -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect
>
> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/leon/asmlibrary/linux/libasmlibrary.so when searching for -lasmlibrary
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasmlibrary
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [ASM_TEST] Error 1
>
> 17:25:54 Build Finished (took 111ms)

Comment: `file /home/leon/asmlibrary/linux/libasmlibrary.so` - what tells you?

Comment: ? I've got the file here.

Comment: Please run: `file /home/leon/asmlibrary/linux/libasmlibrary.so` on your computer.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how I can "run" a library file.

Comment: Oh, I see. Here's the result '/home/leon/asmlibrary/linux/libasmlibrary.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x73c00b87bac6b88e644daa5d754d1834a2e62eff, not stripped'.

Comment: No, you run the command `file`. `file` is just a command and it tells you about a file

Comment: Yeah, got it. I've pasted the result up there.

Comment: It is not suitable for `-m64`. However it is not clear why you cannot use it in `-m32`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange..

Comment: Try builing a simple test program: g++ -m32 main.cpp -lasmlibrary.so. Just to simplify things.

Comment: I mean try simplifing things by building a `Hello, World` program with `-m32` and dependency on your lib.

Comment: let me give it a try.

Comment: Well, this time, it seems that g++ has succesfully linked the library, but some new troubles show up as what happened when I tried to build in Eclipse. '/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
'

Comment: I gave it another try in Eclipse, and it didn't show those errors. But the "asmlibrary" is still skipped.

Comment: On my computer there are two std C++ libs: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 (64-bit) and /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 (32-bit). Just find a correct lib for you.

Comment: I've checked my computer and there's a "lib" folder and a "lib32" folder. However, there's not a libstdc++.so in my lib32 folder. I wonder if the problem is that I'm trying to compile with "-m32" option while linking 64-bit libraries(opencv_*).